# how to add a div in topmenu bar in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, topmenu

I am trying to add a div inside a menu bar, it gets added but it gets displayed below the menu bar. I have added the div as given below in `topmenu.phtml`:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul> 
    <div class="nav" style="background-color:red; width:100px; height:100%; float:right;">
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

**If this is not the right way to add a div, is their any other way?**

Thanks.!

Comment: inside menu bar?? Exactly where?? if have fresh magento copy then just put DOM code

Comment: Question is, what do you want to do with the div? But in all cases: don't use inline CSS.

Comment: I want to add my cart and checkout in that div.

Comment: check `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea try to do it in the template. You should extend the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` class.

Note that `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/r‌​enderer.phtml`is an RWD template, there isn't in all themes.